# How can client know is wcf service is running?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

My service is running currently on

```
localhost:17722/Book.svc
```

How can my client app know if the service running before trying to consume it?

Comment: What binding do you use?

Comment: @ilansch wsHttpBinding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't check to see if a server is up before consuming it. Consume the service and handle any errors that occur during the call.

Even if you check that the service is up it can go down between the time you check that it is up and you call the service.  So even if you check that it is up, you still need to handle it being down when you consume it.

The best way to check if a service is up is to try to use it.

Comment: "..is service running **before trying to consume it**"

Comment: and you propose to use it :)

Comment: @MikroDel - my point is the best way to tell if a service is up is to try to consume it.

Comment: So you answer the question "what is the best way to test it"  but not the question asked

Comment: @MikroDel sometimes the question is phrased by asking how to solve the symptom, not the problem.  When I read the question, I felt it was relating to "How do I handle a service that is potentially not available".

Answer (score 5):

Only some kind of **ping**

but without guarantee, that after you ping was ok the service will be not droped before your real request

To summarize:

Prepare you clint to handle dead service(s), faults etc

Answer (score 4):

I would apply the principal of [Tell, don't ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) in this situation.  Just try to perform whatever operation you were intending on doing, and then handle the exception if it fails.

Why would your program be consuming a service if it was not necessary to the operation of the program?

`Hey service, can I invoke your 'X' method? ... no? ... okay, I didn't want to anyway :P`

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not possible until you try the service (or ping the server). Calling your web service from your client application is like calling any other web service, how can you know that a "google's" web service is running before consuming it?

Once I had a similar problem and I just expose an operation that returns "something" (`return true` for instance) that I called to know if the server application was "operational" and expecting a "timeout" or "500" error when not working.

Answer (score 1):

Setup a dummy method in the svc that returns a bool or something. Then hit it on a background thread at a specified interval. If the request times out you can then handle the timeout by displaying something that says the service is unreachable.